# Best way to package additional modules for 1GP package

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, package, npsp, 1gp-package

We have a first-generation package (let's call it X) on AppExchange. We are building some additional modules (A & B), these modules can't sit inside the main Managed Package X because the functionalities offered by these modules are not in line with the long-term vision of the Product. It does however makes sense to have them as an additional module that can be installed on top of package X.

In the past, we have built extension packages that have met the requirement but as our Product is growing it will be difficult to manage extension packages.

I would like to know two things:

1. Is extension packages the right way to go? Is there a better way to deliver this?
2. How does the [NPSP installer](https://install.salesforce.org/products/npsp/install) work? I'm assuming they also have extension packages. If so what would be the best way to go about building an Installer similar to NPSP's?

Let me know if this needs more info. Thanks!

Comment: Use 2GP managed extension packages. You have to write scripting to ensure dependencies are installed in your scratch orgs for development,  but otherwise this is very straight forward and is what we do already. Sadly the extension packages cannot be in the same namespace as the core package so the boundary is still defined using `global` apex. However, you can use NamespaceAccessible annotations to internally expose stuff between your extension packages. Last point: avoid name clashes - you cannot have the same named Apex class in multiple 2GPs in the same namespace if the packages co-install.

Answer (score 2):

*Disclosure: I am on the CumulusCI Suite team at Salesforce*.

NPSP's installer is built on [MetaDeploy](https://github.com/SFDO-Tooling/MetaDeploy), a free and open source application running on Heroku.

MetaDeploy harnesses product automation build with [CumulusCI](https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) ([Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/build-applications-with-cumulusci)), an orchestration framework on top of Salesforce DX and scratch orgs.

CumulusCI and MetaDeploy are designed in part to facilitate the Product Delivery Model, which is built on the notion that a *product* can include multiple managed packages as well as unpackaged metadata and setup automation. CumulusCI orchestrates the deployment of all of those elements, including a sophisticated dependency management system, and MetaDeploy allows you to expose that automation directly to customers.

NPSP includes a total of six managed packages with three levels of interdependency, as well as unpackaged metadata.

CumulusCI Suite works with both first- and second-generation packages.

Answer (score 0):

(1)

Extension packages are annoying but sometimes they are the best way to solve the problem of providing functionality to a subset of customers without bloating the main package.

As Phil W mentions, putting multiple extension packages in a single 2GP namespace, even if the main package is 1GP, can make extensions less annoying (or at least more interesting).

The only alternative I've found is Feature Management or some kind of homebrew feature toggle. It doesn't keep the functionality out of the main package, but it gives you the option of keeping the feature dark in the future.

(2)

I haven't used the NPSP installer much, but yes they use multiple packages.

We use the SFDX CLI with Jenkins and AWS to deploy multiple packages (both 1GP and 2GP) in a certain order to a large group of customers. But it's not an installer that we distribute, we run it according to a pre-arranged schedule.

I know other people do the same thing with the push API but I don't know the details. But, again, not as a local installer.

In any case, I find that some upgrades will fail at the platform level, mainly because the org is too busy. Usually, restarting the upgrade that fails works, so our Jenkins project is designed to let us restart the stack of packages at any point.

HTH, Ted.
https://github.com/DreamOps/og-sfdx